# How to use wildcards for filtering an Object Set based on a string property in ts-queries (Palantir Foundry OSS)?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-functions

While implementing some search functionality using the `StringPropertyFilter::fuzzyMatchAllTokens` method I stumbled across the `WILDCARD ObjectSetFilterType`.
Filtering of a string property using wildcards is neither mentioned in the documentation about Object Sets nor is there any method defined in the `StringPropertyFilter` class using this filter type.

Wildcards would be very handy in our use case to extend the the expressiveness of the search queries and to improve the search for Objects.
Is there a way to use wildcards to filter Object Sets?

Comment: Wildcard is currently not available. I'll delete this comment and add an answer should this change.